# BubbleSort on Custom LinkedList

Tags: java, linked-list, customization, bubble-sort

I am trying to sort the 'Data'. The Data is suppose to be sorted by numbers. I am trying to implement BubbleSort(), but unable to process the same.

```
    public void bubbleSort() {       
    if (isEmpty())
    {
        System.out.println("The Empty List Is Already Sorted");
    }
    else if (first.next == null) {
        System.out.println("One Element List Is Already Sorted");
    }
    else {
        Node current = first;
        boolean swapDone = true;
        while (swapDone) {

            swapDone = false;

            while (current != null) { 

                if (current.next != null && current.value.getScore() >                     current.next.value.getScore()) {

                    Data temp = current.value;
                    current.value.setScore(current.next.value.getScore());
                    current.value.setName(current.next.value.getName());
                    current.next.value.setScore(temp.getScore());  
                    current.next.value.setName(temp.getName());                        
                }
                current = current.next;
            }
            current = first;
        }
    }
```

Comment: @CyberneticTwerkGuruOrc I am using while, it's the same.

Comment: @user3337714 you have set `swapDone=false` inside the outer loop and never updated it. So it will make outer loop run only once.

Answer (score 1):

check out this code if it works

```
public void bubbleSort() {       
    if (isEmpty())
    {
        System.out.println("The Empty List Is Already Sorted");
    }
    else if (first.next == null) {
        System.out.println("One Element List Is Already Sorted");
    }
    else {
        Node current = first;
        boolean swapDone = true;
        while (swapDone) {

            swapDone = false;

            while (current != null) { 

                if (current.next != null && current.value.getScore() >  current.next.value.getScore()) {

                    Data temp = current.value;
                    current.value.setScore(current.next.value.getScore());
                    current.value.setName(current.next.value.getName());
                    current.next.value.setScore(temp.getScore());  
                    current.next.value.setName(temp.getName());    
                    swapDone=true;                    
                }
                current = current.next;
            }
            current = first;
        }
    }
```

Comment: If I Pass Two Number
     Obj1: 180
     Obj2: 60

It Prints
Obj2: 20
Obj2: 20

The above code.

Comment: and where is the print statement? and i that you haven't provided with your code

Comment: the print statement are running in another method. This is one of the methods of my code. I am literally unable to figure out what's wrong.

Comment: i don't think there is any problem with this method other than optimization. check if you are modifying variables somewhere else.

Comment: I am not modifying anywhere else. This is simply the method which deals with the variables. The Print method, simply prints the LinkedList. @Fraser Price

Answer (score 0):

swapDone will always be false after the first loop. You will only go through the inner loop once

Comment: So am I suppose to update the swapDone inside the 'if' statement after the swap, i.e. 
swapDone = true;
@maxx777 and Fraser Price

Comment: You need to update swapDone at the end of the inner loop. If there have been no changes in that pass of the algorithm, this should be false (else remain true).

Comment: Also, the name swapDone is misleading. The primary loop will exit if this value is false rather than if it is true.

Comment: this is what i have done with your code. Check if it works. suggestion provided by @fraser is also good. Give a try to that one also.

Answer (score 0):

This Is The Working Code.

```
public void bubbleSort() {       
if (isEmpty())
{
    System.out.println("The Empty List Is Already Sorted");
}
else if (first.next == null) {
    System.out.println("One Element List Is Already Sorted");
}
else {
    Node current = first;
    boolean swapDone = true;
    while (swapDone) {

        swapDone = false;

        while (current != null) { 

            if (current.next != null && current.value.getScore() >
                                   current.next.value.getScore()) {

                Data temp = current.value;
                current.value = current.next.value;
                current.next.value = temp;
                swapDone = true;                      
            }
            current = current.next;
        }
        current = first;
    }
}
```